# As a LDAP client, do I need to know the LDAP db schema before I do a ldapsearch?

Tags: ldap

The reason I think so because only I know the schema - how the directory tree organized, then I can know how to make a query using ldapsearch filter properly.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP schema doesn't give you how the Directory tree is organised, but what are the possible objects and their attributes.
Knowing the schema will allow you to interpret better the content of entries and decide how to display values, compare or process them.